# Postgresql programming while I am creating a project on Windows application there is a error to send data to database

Tags: postgresql

```
INSERT INTO answer(userans) 
VALUES(OptionA) 

SELECT username 
FROM answer 
WHERE username= 'Name'
```

I want to add a data in a column with reference to another column in same table.

Answer (score 2):

You may phrase this as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO answer (userans, username)
SELECT 'OptionA', username
FROM answer
WHERE username = 'Some Name';
```

Note: I'm assuming that `OptionA` is a placeholder for some literal value, e.g. a number or string.  You can't put a column name into a `VALUES` clause.